# View Desktop PC using Android device

Tags: android, wifi

How should I view Desktop PC from Android device programmatically where android device and PC are in same WiFi connection?

Is there any way to access it under same WiFi same condition?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the vnc protocol, there are some apps there that you could try